# How to iterate only through defined indexes in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to iterate only through indexes I've defined in an array in angularjs, like so:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.days = new Array();
$scope.days[4] = true;
$scope.days[7] = true;
```

**Template:**

```
<!-- Had to add 'track by $index' to suppress 'Duplicate in a repeater' error-->
<div ng-repeat="(day, value) in days track by $index"> 
    {{day}}: {{value}}
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
0:

1:

2:

3:

4: true

5:

6:

7: true
```

Why is ng-repeat 'filling in the gap' indexes? How can I make it only print indexes I've explicitly defined? If I console.log out my array, it only prints my defined indexes.

Comment: You should not be using an array.

Comment: They are showing up because you have created an array with length 8, regardless of whether you have specified every index.  Any index you haven't defined is `undefined`, so you could either create a filter or use something like `ng-if` to conditionally show `{{day}}: {{value}}`.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your code with object literal:

```
$scope.days = { 4: true, 7: true }
```

Or change your logic and put values in array:

```
$scope.days = [4,7]
```